# Reciprocal solutions of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I need to show that if $a$ is a constant and $b(x)$ is a function, then
> $$y''+\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)}y'-\frac{a^2}{[b(x)]^2}y=0$$
> has a pair of linearly independent solutions which are reciprocal and then find them.

I would have thought I could just substitute in $y=u(x)+\dfrac{1}{u(x)}$ but I seem to get nowhere.

Anyway, we have $y'=u'-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}$ and $y''=u''-\dfrac{u''}{u^2}+\dfrac{2(u')^2}{u^3}$.  Therefore, we get $$u''-\frac{u''}{u^2}+\frac{2(u')^2}{u^3}+(\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)})(u'-\frac{u'}{u^2})-(\frac{a^2}{[b(x)]^2})(u(x)+\frac{1}{u(x)})=0\,.$$

tidying gives

$$-\frac{u''}{u^2}+\frac{2(u')^2}{u^3}+(\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)})(-\frac{u'}{u^2})-(\frac{a^2}{[b(x)]^2})(\frac{1}{u(x)})=0\,.$$

multiply by $-u^2$ to get

$$u''-\frac{2(u')^2}{u}+(\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)})(u')+(\frac{a^2}{[b(x)]^2})(u(x))=0\,.$$

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want us to help you?  Then show where you substitution led, and ask for help.  Or do you want us to do your work for you?   It sounds like you're expecting the latter.

Comment: I need to show that this differential equation has reciprocal solutions

Comment: Yes, I know what *you* need to show.  But that declaration is not a question.  What more have you done (add it to your post, the work you claim, at a miminum, and the subsequent result), and *ask* a question, please.  And note, it is ultimately *your* responsibility to do your own work.  Now, how can we help you to show what *you* need to show.?

Comment: If I do the substitution I get $y=u+u^{-1}$, $y'=u'-\frac{u'}{u^2}$ and $y''=u''-\frac{u''}{u^2}+\frac{2(u')^2}{u^3}$.  Substituting gives $u''-\frac{u''}{u^2}+\frac{2(u')^2}{u^3}+\frac{u'b'}{b}-\frac{b'u'}{bu^2}-\frac{ua^2}{[b]^2}-\frac{a^2}{u[b]^2}$ and this doesn't seem to tidy to much

Comment: Great start: please edit your "question post" to include your last comment.

Comment: The question makes more sense, if you assume $y=u(x)$ is a solution and $y=1/u(x)$ is also a solution then you can derive a neat form for $u$ in terms of $a$ and $b(x)$.

Comment: But if I have to show that the solutions are reciprocal surely I can't just assume they are. I would have thought that I have to show it in some way

Comment: In the study of differential equations, you will find that it is often productive to start with an *ansatz* (or assumption) that a solution has some particular form, then work the problem backwards to determine conditions under which that *ansatz* gives you something reasonable.  This is essentially the entire game that leads to the study of characteristic polynomials or the technique of separation of variables in the study of PDEs.

Comment: Is that not what I am trying to do by assuming a solution of the form $y=u(x)=\frac{1}{u(x)}$ ? I really can't see how I can get anywhere.

Comment: In response to Donald Splutterwit's suggestion when I tried this all I got was the same line:$u''-\frac{2(u')^2}{u}+\frac{b'u'}{b}+\frac{a^2u}{b^2}=0$ not a neat form for $u$ in terms of $a$ and $b(x)$. If he has time to show his working that might help. I've spent days on this yet the text book (Bender and Orzag's Asymptotic Methods and Perturbation Theory) has this as an easy question.

Comment: I have now had a chance to ask my tutor who looked as baffled as I have been. Clearly this is not such a simple question despite what the text book states. If anyone can find an answer I would be most grateful. I have some more ideas but I may go down the bounty route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got so close. Suppose that $y_1=u$ is a solution, then $y_2=1/u$ must also be a solution. Substituting this, we obtain

$$ u'' -2\frac{(u')^2}{u} + \frac{b'}{b}u' + \frac{a^2}{b^2}u = 0 $$

But we already know that

$$ u'' + \frac{b'}{b}u' = \frac{a^2}{b^2}u $$

From the given assumption. Therefore

$$ 2\frac{a^2}{b^2}u - 2\frac{(u')^2}{u} = 0 \implies \frac{u'}{u} = \pm\frac{a}{b} $$

Integrating both sides gives

$$ u(x) = c\exp\left(\pm \int \frac{a}{b(x)} dx\right) $$

where $c$ is some arbitrary constant. Taking the positive and negative signs to be distinct solutions, we can put together the general solution

$$ y(x) = c_1 \exp\left(\int \frac{a}{b(x)}dx \right) + c_2 \exp\left(-\int \frac{a}{b(x)}dx\right) $$

which is indeed a linear combination of two reciprocal functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Annoyingly I did actually get all the way to the penultimate line but didn't think that these were reciprocals despite the plus/minus ..... I will now try to work out how to make sure you get the bounty.

Comment: You can keep it, I don't think you need to give it out when you got so close to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This is probably not the expected answer, but in fact you can integrate the equation.

$$b(x)y''(x)+b'(x)y'(x)=(b(x)y'(x))'=\frac{a^2y(x)}{b(x)},$$ and multiplying by $b(x)y'(x)$,

$$b(x)y'(x)(b(x)y'(x))'=a^2y(x)y'(x).$$

By integration,

$$(b(x)y'(x))^2=a^2y^2(x)+c.$$

This is a separable equation,

$$\frac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{a^2y^2(x)+c}}=\pm\frac1{b(x)}.$$

$$\frac1a\text{arcosh}\frac{ay(x)}{\sqrt c}=\pm\int\frac{dx}{b(x)}$$ (for negative $c$, $\text{arsinh}$).

Comment: I had noticed that I could write it in that form but the last bit I certainly hadn't realised ... nice